# Error Linking References in Android App (Styles)

Tags: android, xml, android-gradle-plugin

I was working on my android app when I created a color for my `AppTheme` theme. In the `colors.xml` file, I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="materialGrey">#737373</color>
    <color name="divider_color">#212121</color>
</resources>
```

Now in my `styles.xml` file, I have this.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="materialGrey">@color/materialGrey</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="Seperator">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/divider_color</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And these are the build errors I am getting for my Android App-

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
C:\Users\varunsom\IdeaProjects\ReliefProjects\ReliefSecondv2\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml
Error:error: style attribute 'attr/materialGrey (aka org.reliefdev.worldchanger:attr/materialGrey)' not found.
C:\Users\varunsom\IdeaProjects\ReliefProjects\ReliefSecondv2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Error:(817) style attribute 'attr/materialGrey (aka org.reliefdev.worldchanger:attr/materialGrey)' not found.
Error:failed linking references.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED in 14m 27s
Information:7 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

This is my Gradle Console output:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:prepareLintJar
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 7m 35s
22 actionable tasks: 12 executed, 10 up-to-date
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Observed package id 'platform-tools' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdk1.5\platform-tools' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\platform-tools')
Observed package id 'platforms;android-2' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdk1.5\platforms\android-1.1' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\platforms\android-2')
Observed package id 'platforms;android-17' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdk1.5\platforms\android-1.5' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\platforms\android-17')
Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdk1.5\tools' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\tools')
Observed package id 'build-tools;20.0.0' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdk20-stub\build-tools\20.0.0' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\build-tools\20.0.0')
Already observed package id 'build-tools;20.0.0' in 'C:\Users\varunsom\build-tools\20.0.0'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdk20-stub\build-tools\20.0.0'
Observed package id 'docs' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdk20-stub\docs' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\docs')
Observed package id 'platform-tools' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdk20-stub\platform-tools' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\platform-tools')
Already observed package id 'platform-tools' in 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdk1.5\platform-tools'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdk20-stub\platform-tools'
Observed package id 'platforms;android-19' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdk20-stub\platforms\android-19' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\platforms\android-19')
Observed package id 'platforms;android-20' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdk20-stub\platforms\android-20' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\platforms\android-20')
Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdk20-stub\tools' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\tools')
Already observed package id 'tools' in 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdk1.5\tools'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdk20-stub\tools'
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_gdk-google-19' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\add-ons\addon-google_gdk-google-19' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\add-ons\addon-google_gdk-google-19')
Observed package id 'build-tools;18.1.1' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\build-tools\18.1.1' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\build-tools\18.1.1')
Observed package id 'build-tools;19.0.0' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\build-tools\19.0.0' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\build-tools\19.0.0')
Observed package id 'build-tools;19.0.1' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\build-tools\19.0.1' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\build-tools\19.0.1')
Observed package id 'build-tools;19.0.2' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\build-tools\19.0.2' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\build-tools\19.0.2')
Observed package id 'build-tools;19.0.3' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\build-tools\19.0.3' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\build-tools\19.0.3')
Observed package id 'build-tools;19.1.0' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\build-tools\19.1.0' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\build-tools\19.1.0')
Already observed package id 'build-tools;19.1.0' in 'C:\Users\varunsom\build-tools\19.1.0'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\build-tools\19.1.0'
Observed package id 'build-tools;20.0.0' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\build-tools\20.0.0' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\build-tools\20.0.0')
Already observed package id 'build-tools;20.0.0' in 'C:\Users\varunsom\build-tools\20.0.0'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\build-tools\20.0.0'
Observed package id 'extras;android;m2repository' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\extras\android\m2repository' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\extras\android\m2repository')
Observed package id 'extras;android;support' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\extras\android\support' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\extras\android\support')
Observed package id 'extras;google;m2repository' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\extras\google\m2repository' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\extras\google\m2repository')
Observed package id 'platform-tools' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\platform-tools' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\platform-tools')
Already observed package id 'platform-tools' in 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdk1.5\platform-tools'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\platform-tools'
Observed package id 'platforms;android-10' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\platforms\android-10' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\platforms\android-10')
Observed package id 'platforms;android-14' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\platforms\android-14' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\platforms\android-14')
Observed package id 'platforms;android-15' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\platforms\android-15' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\platforms\android-15')
Observed package id 'platforms;android-16' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\platforms\android-16' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\platforms\android-16')
Observed package id 'platforms;android-17' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\platforms\android-17' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\platforms\android-17')
Already observed package id 'platforms;android-17' in 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdk1.5\platforms\android-1.5'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\platforms\android-17'
Observed package id 'platforms;android-18' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\platforms\android-18' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\platforms\android-18')
Observed package id 'platforms;android-19' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\platforms\android-19' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\platforms\android-19')
Already observed package id 'platforms;android-19' in 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdk20-stub\platforms\android-19'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\platforms\android-19'
Observed package id 'platforms;android-20' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\platforms\android-20' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\platforms\android-20')
Already observed package id 'platforms;android-20' in 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdk20-stub\platforms\android-20'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\platforms\android-20'
Observed package id 'platforms;android-8' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\platforms\android-8' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\platforms\android-8')
Observed package id 'platforms;android-L' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\platforms\android-L' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\platforms\android-L')
Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\tools' (Expected 'C:\Users\varunsom\tools')
Already observed package id 'tools' in 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdk1.5\tools'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\varunsom\Documents\GitHub\intellij-community\android\android\testData\sdkL-stub\tools'
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: style attribute \u0027attr/materialGrey (aka org.reliefdev.worldchanger:attr/materialGrey)\u0027 not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\varunsom\\IdeaProjects\\ReliefProjects\\ReliefSecondv2\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles.xml"}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
C:\Users\varunsom\IdeaProjects\ReliefProjects\ReliefSecondv2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:817: error: style attribute 'attr/materialGrey (aka org.reliefdev.worldchanger:attr/materialGrey)' not found.
error: failed linking references.

Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:454)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:411)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
    at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14m 27s

12 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 9 up-to-date
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: `<item name="materialGrey">` - There is no `materialGrey` attribute, unless you've defined it yourself, or it's supposed to be defined in a library. Did you mean something else there?

Comment: But I have defined `materialGrey` in `colors.xml` and linked it in `styles.xml`

Comment: You've defined a _color_ resource there, not an _attribute_. The _color_ is between the tags - `<item name="materialGrey">@color/materialGrey</item>`. That error message is saying the `name="materialGrey"` part is wrong.

Comment: Then how would I go about creating this color for my project. Would this `materialGrey` color have to be outside of the `<style name="AppTheme ...>`?

Comment: You've apparently already created the `materialGrey` color resource. Now you just set it on attributes that take a color. As mentioned, there is no `materialGrey` attribute, though, so it's not clear what you're trying to do there.

Comment: So would it go like this: `<item name="android:color">@color/materialGrey </item>`?